# Forward port from iphone to local machine programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to forward a port from an iPhone to a local machine, where that iPhone is connected to my local machine. Please suggest a solution or where to start

i have tried [tcmportmapper](http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/) and [asyncsocket](https://github.com/twyatt/asyncsocket-example) but I couldn't find the proper way of doing exactly what I want to.

Any pointers?

Comment: And, while we're asking questions, what are you actually trying to accomplish here? iPhones don't usually accept network connections, so it sounds like you're trying to do something unusual.

Comment: @duskwuff yes it is unusual ... i can not find api just wanted to make sure if any actual way is possible ... ?